# Ipython web server using a FIOS router

Tags: python, webserver, ipython

I'm trying to setup my headless home server so that I can access a ipython notebook via a web browser. I think the issue I'm having is setting up the port forwarding correctly from my Verizon FIOS router. I've looked at a number of posts that include how to do this but to no avail.

I've setup an ipython web server before on work servers with no problem. I've also done it on AWS. Which leads me to think I'm doing something wrong, but completely unobvious to me, with the port fowarding. Has anyone tried to do something like this on a Verzion FIOS router and succeeded? I've tried this [how to setup a webserver with FIOS](http://nerdposts.blogspot.com/2009/04/web-how-to-set-up-web-server-w-fios.html), and variations of this, such as only opening up a port and not changing the 'forward to port', rather using any, etc.

Add advice would be appreciated! thanks.